Authenticate an endpoint using Kerberos
I am hosting a simple endpoint in a console application that looks like this
string[] prefixes = { "http://+:8080/" };
HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();

foreach (string prefix in prefixes)
{
    listener.Prefixes.Add(prefix);
}

listener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate;
listener.Start();

Console.WriteLine("Listening on port 8080...");

while (true)
{
    HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
    HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
    HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;

    if (request.HttpMethod == "GET" && request.Url.AbsolutePath == "/api/kerberos/test")
    {
        IIdentity identity = context.User.Identity;
        string responseString = $"Hello, {identity.Name}! You are authenticated using {identity.AuthenticationType}.";
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);

        response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
        response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }
    else
    {
        response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
    }

response.Close();

The console application is being executed from a PowerShell window on an VM running AD. Once the application is running, I navigate to http://{FQDN}//api/kerberos/test, I am prompted to enter my Windows username and password I always get Hello, DOMAIN\john.smith! You are authenticated using NTLM.. What would I need to do to see Hello, DOMAIN\user! You are authenticated using Kerberos.
Here are the things I have tried so far

setspn -Q HTTP/{FQDN}
setspn -S HTTP/{FQDN} john.smith

I feel like this is an issue with the SPN but I am pretty new to Kerberos so any help would be apprecaited.
Thank you

Are both the client and server machines joined to the domain, as well as the account running the client and server applications? Please show the output of setspn -L {serverhostname} I think you need setspn -S HTTP/{FQDN}:{portnumber} {accountname} where accountname is the FQ-account-name that is running the service. If running as SYSTEM then you need the hostname instead.

The client and the server are on the same machine.  The client is a Chrome browser and the Server is my console application above.

The output of setspn -L {serverhostname} is HTTP/{FQDN of the machine}:8080

Please use the following format for SPN registration:
http/webserver1.contoso.com:8080
Here webserver1.contoso.com is the FQDN of the server providing web server service, in your case the FQDN of the domain controller.
This SPN should be registered under application pool account of your application's application pool if using IIS.
The browser you are using should support Windows integrated authentication.
"Verify that the Web server is configured to support Kerberos authentication. To do this, verify that the setting for the NTAuthenticationProviders key in the IIS metabase has not been changed to NTLM. The default setting is Negotiate,NTLM."
You may also use klist command to check the Kerberos tickets that you obtain for http/webserver1.contoso.com.
If you are using Internet Explorer browser, you should set the registry key below explained in the link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-authentication-authorization/troubleshoot-kerberos-failures-ie
"Does the web server use a port other than default (80)
By default, Internet Explorer doesn't include the port number information in the SPN that's used to request a Kerberos ticket. It can be a problem if you use IIS to host multiple sites under different ports and identities. In this configuration, Kerberos authentication may work only for specific sites even if all SPNs have been correctly declared in Active Directory. To fix this issue, you must set the FEATURE_INCLUDE_PORT_IN_SPN_KB908209 registry value. (See the Internet Explorer feature keys section for information about how to declare the key.) This setting forces Internet Explorer to include the port number in the SPN that's used to request the Kerberos ticket"
If you are using Chrome, you may check the following link:
https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/10304441?hl=en
I think your logon should be automatic using current credentials. It should not ask for user and password.
